# DataAnnotations CustomValidation not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

I've created a really simple code to test CustomValidations yet it is not working:

Validation

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
namespace UniversidadeCorporativa.Util
{
    public class CustomDDD : ValidationAttribute
    {
    private Regex _regex = new Regex(@"^[1-9]{2}$");

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {

        if (_regex.IsMatch(value.ToString()))
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

ViewModel

```
using UniversidadeCorporativa.Util;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
namespace UniversidadeCorporativa.ViewModels
{
    public class TesteViewModel
    {
        public TesteViewModel()
        { }

        [Required]
        [CustomDDD]
        [Display(Name = "DDD")]
        public int DDDCel { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Celular")]
        public int Celular { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Controller

```
using UniversidadeCorporativa.ViewModels;
public ActionResult Teste()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Teste(TesteViewModel model)
{
    try
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Teste");
    }
    catch
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

View

```
@model UniversidadeCorporativa.ViewModels.TesteViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Teste";
}

<h2>Teste</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm("Teste", "Universidade", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @*@Html.ValidationSummary("", new { @class = "text-danger" })*@
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Celular, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-2">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DDDCel, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DDDCel)
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Celular, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Celular)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Teste" />
        </div>
    </div>
}

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Nothing is validated when the input is submited and i have no ideia why. Can someone help?

Comment: Where do you want the validation to execute?  I don't see any code that does any validation.  (I don't see you checking in the controller for `ModelState.IsValid` nor do I see any javascript that does validation).

Comment: MVC already has a `RegularExpressionAttribute` (which gives client and server side validation). Why are you trying to reinvent the wheel? (and you can always extends that attribute so that the regex is built in to it and you can use just `[CustomDDD ]` rather than `[RegularExpression(@"^[1-9]{2}$")]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add a custom validation, you will have to test for it server side by checking `ModelState.IsValid` on your Teste action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Teste(TesteViewModel model)
{
    try
    {
        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // your model is valid!
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Teste");
    }
    catch
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

As it stands, a CustomValidation attribute will not be automatically hooked into jQuery's unobtrusive validation library. So, it won't work client-side until you create a custom jQuery validation rule. See [this blog post](https://thewayofcode.wordpress.com/2012/01/18/custom-unobtrusive-jquery-validation-with-data-annotations-in-mvc-3/) for reference.